# Visio how do I restore layout defaults?

Tags: visio, orgchart

I have built an org chart in Visio. I have been fooling with the automatic layout and then tried dragging things to where I want them. I guess the dragging creates overrides of the automated layout, and I cannot find a way to delete the overrides to get back to defaults. Is there any evidence that Visio has not become a total piece of crap?
Here is what the Re-Layout button does now [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbwRm.png)